# Unstable multiple USB devices (of same type == LTE modems)

Tags: windows, networking, usb, proxy

I have a "setup" for LTE modems, around 50 LTE sticks on each setup, most of same Huawei type but also some ZTE.

- I use Windows 10 to manage all connected devices.
- All devices connected with USB hubs and power supply

I buy all most expensive peripheral.

But still each time I connect a new device there is a big chance some others will stop working, I noticed "others" are connected to the same controller, so it will not break other controller (chip on motherboard).

Sometimes reinsert them will make them work and some time Windows will report malfunction USB device so I need to find a different port.

This happens on both of my setups which are completely different PCs.

I am a software engineer in networking.

- What tips can I get to mange the setup correctly?
- How can I analyze the issues of usb devices?
- What am I doing wrong?

Here is a screenshot of the device manager in Windows:

[image: USB device manager view by connections]

Comment: Perhaps verify the DHCP settings?

Comment: In what way do they "stop working"? Are these USB2 or USB3 devices? Are they connected to a USB2 hub or USB3? Is the USB port the hubs are connected to USB2 or 3? Bear in mind that all USB devices will share bandwidth, not only for actual data transfers but there will be overheads for general device polling and communications. 50 devices all trying to provide constant updates on connection state, signal strength and so on will quickly eat up your bandwidth.

Comment: verify the DHCP settings? I do have diffrent ip for each.

Comment: I don't have bandwidth issues, the setup can run smooth for weeks. all devices and hubs and motherboard are usb3, maybe some do have usb2 hubs but very rear. "stop working" I mean they are not responding to windows command, the NIC interface is gone, but the device it self light blue (4g) indicate connection is just fine. sometimes I do have the device light torn on and off, mostly this is a power supply issue, but my problems are more OS related.

Comment: 50 at the same time?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas yes they all running at the same time, it just connecting/ reconnecting/ reboot of PC that can cause some usb to fail. but once it works it mostly works ... I do use only 0/5 MB/s.

Answer (score 0):

Although it sounds like too many, you can have up to 127 USB devices attached to a computer. You will need to use a good, powered USB hub with powered ports - Most huawei/zte dongles draw 500ma so the hub power supply must have the amperage to suit. 5amp would supply 10x modems. Each hub ideally needs to be plugged into a USB port on the computer and if you get a 5amp powered hub with 10 ports this should be sufficient. The most important part of the hub you choose is the power supply attached to it - It must not be lower than 5 amps.

This article on USB in general is a very good write up on how to check the amperage and USB setup.

[USB Hub information](https://support.rm.com/TechnicalArticle.asp?cref=TEC2021918&nav=0&referrer=rss)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think this is the case. I do have some powered hubs of 2.4A and 4 - 5connected devices, also other hubs connected to this hub since the PC is miussing USB ports. The issues are when I connect / Disconnect new device. once the setup is working it mostly works fine. BTW I have an ampermeter to test the usb port and is mostly on 0.2A, but it can go to 750mA (from hawii manual)